# What FDA compliant plastics can have contact with alochol (wine)?

Tags: plastic

I am able to find that the class for materials that can be in contact with wine (~10-15% alcohol by volume) is called Class VI-A and Class VI-C, but I am not able to find a list of materials that are approved for those classes. Does anyone have experience with navigating the FDA for a list of materials that are approved for a certain class of use?

https://www.fda.gov/RegulatoryInformation/Guidances/ucm081818.htm

Comment: Each specific polymer blend has to be certified, since additives etc. can throw things off, even if the base material is typically considered to be food safe. What are the other factors that affect your choice of material? Do you need to be transparent? rigid? tough?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift  Good to know about the additives. It needs to be rigid enough to hold its shape, but can have some flex. Basically it's small diameter bent piping/tubing.